# Let $\phi$ be a Euclidean function, prove that if $a|b$ and $\phi (a) = \phi (b)$, then $a\sim b$

Tags: number-theory, functions

Let $\phi$ be a Euclidean function, prove that if $a|b$ and $\phi (a) = \phi (b)$, then $a\sim b$.

So this means that $b=\gamma a$ for some $\gamma$, but beyond this I haven't been able to get everywhere.  The quotient-divisor property seems like the thing I need to use but despite playing around with it for a while now I just can't figure out the trick.  Essentially I'm trying to show that $\gamma$ is a unit, but so far no luck.

Can anyone help?  Thanks.

Comment: How does $\phi$ behave when applied to the product of 2 integers?

Comment: Well in general $\phi (nm)\geq \phi (n)$, for any integral domain on which a euclidean function can be defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $$a=bq+r$$

Then

$$a|a, a|b \Rightarrow a|r \,.$$

From here, you should get that $r =0$, otherwise you have $a|r$ and $\phi(r)< \phi(b)=\phi(a)$.